# Is there a popular name for this bit-related expression?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Is there a popular name for this?:

```
#define ALL_BITS_SET(value, mask) ((value & mask) == mask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called "contains", after the equivalent operation on sets.

Comment: The reference to bitset is very nice. Of course, contains here would mean includes another set, not just an element (or singleton). Is it part of a standard language library?

Comment: @aka.nice it's not provided in `std::bitset` or `System.Collections.Specialized.BitVector32` and those are the only standard libraries I know something about, so I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In Smalltalk, we long have this Integer method

```
allMask: mask 
    "Treat the argument as a bit mask. Answer whether all of the bits that 
    are 1 in the argument are 1 in the receiver."

    ^mask = (self bitAnd: mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

Signal masking | Bit Masking | Masking

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `ALL_BITS_SET`. It'a just a simple test to check whether `value` is equal to the bit combination represented by `mask`.